# Laravel 9 with Vite, mixing .css and .js files into one?

Tags: php, laravel, vite, laravel-9, laravel-vite

How do you deal with mixing multiple .css and .js files into one which [laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix) used to do so far.

The new **Laravel 9** comes with [Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev/) installed and [laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix) removed. As the main function for which we mostly used [laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix) was to mix the files from the /resource folder into the /public folder (many files into one). How are you dealing with this or are you still using laravel mix along with Vite?

Comment: I import the .js files from ...../js/Composables into my <script setup> || https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBeO62ryQLY

Comment: Have you found any solution so far?

Answer (score -4):

They replace mix with vite... everything else is same. 
Tip..

> Create fresh laravel 9 proj... 
> Install jetstream with inertia..All sets up resources/js , resources/components , app.js ... Vue3.

```
Just db migrate ,artisan serve , and npm run dev ....
```

Comment: I didn't ask about that : )